# c# and Lists: How do I use the foreach loop to retrieve the objects form my list?

Tags: c#, android

this is quite the nooby questions, it's just that I havn't been doing this for a long time and would need some help.

So here is the problem. I have this debug info on my list "lstfriendlist":
[image]

I simply put up a breakpoint in my activity, then clicked on my list and saw, that all my "friends" are brought to me on this list under "friendUsername".

I was able to retrieve a certain username via:

```
        string temp = lstfriendList[11].friendUsername.ToString();
```

This returns "torben" on my string "temp".

Now I just forgot how to use the foreach loop to retrieve all objects in order from my list and then write them down. I'm sorry to bother you with this, but I simply forgot :(

I hope you can help me.
Thank you :)

Comment: What do you mean with "write them down"? What do you want to do with those names? You already _have_ all of them in a list, so putting them in another list seems strange.

Comment: I still wonder why someone instead of writing a long text, run a screen capture, loading the image on a website for a simple question on syntax  don't go directly to the source of the information that he/she needs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Comment: you are aware that you can to a inline List.foreach() using lamda / extension methods.. also did  you for get how to type `Google.com` in the browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have declared a variable of the type "Friend" in the foreach loop's head. Now you can access the properties of the current object by typing

```
foreach (Friend f in lstfriendList)
{
    string temp = f.friendUsername;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete Sebastian Hofmann answer, you can use .OrderBy or .OrderByDescending to order on name or username

```
foreach (Friend f in lstfriendList.OrderBy(list => list.friendUsername))
{
    string temp = f.friendUsername;
}
```

Will return user name from a to z

```
foreach (Friend f in lstfriendList.OrderByDescending(list => list.friendUsername))
{
    string temp = f.friendUsername;
}
```

Will return username z to a

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to stuck there, since you are now having the `Friend` object(`f`) with you inside the loop, just place a `.` after `f` and see what intellisense suggests, Anyway It is pretty good if you modify the class like the following, with [override ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method):

```
class Friend
{
    public string friendUsername { get; set; }
    public int friendId { get; set; }
    // Add rest of properties here
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ID :" + friendId +  "\n Friend Name: " + friendUsername;
        // Append rest of properties here
    }
}
```

And then use like this:

```
foreach (Friend f in lstfriendList)
{
    string friendDetails = f.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(friendDetails);
}
```